# cakephp plugin calls a model I already have set up

Tags: cakephp, plugins

In my cakePHP app I am implementing Miles Johson's Forum Plugin (http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/forum).

It creates a model named Profile in the plugin.  I already have a model named Profile in my normal app, and as a result am getting a lot of errors when I use the forum. Combining the two models into one doesn't seem like a good option because they are used for very different purposes.

Is there an easy way to change model names in a plugin without hours of searching for every instance of "Profile" or "Forum.Profile" and changing it to "ForumProfile" and "Forum.ForumProfile"?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for you to change your Profile model to SiteProfile or something else then alias it?

Comment: also you could "search/replace" your ForumProfile - any decent IDE can do this in a single operation

Comment: @mark that's what I ended up going. The challenge of course is that opens the process up to a lot of user error (searching Forum pulls up the Forum from both plugin and app). Extra work but it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add another connection to your database.php, something like 'forums' and configure it to use a prefix 'forums_'. In the ForumsAppModel override the constructor and use your forums connection and prefix. You'll need to prefix all you forum tables with 'forums_'.

I do not understand why the forum plugin was not directly done with prefixes for the tables and everything.

Comment: The plugin was done with prefixes for the table, and it's all set up for the Profile (for the forum) to draw from the forum_profile database table.  The issue is there are two models named Profile (one in app and one in profile). My hope was that there was an easy built-in way (such as the database prefix) to do the same thing except with the model names.